Cloning repo failed
I was cloning repository from GitHub and this happened "RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) 3004 bytes of body are still expected fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet early EOF fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output" I don't know how to fix it
I ask copilot ai but I don't trust the answear

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+RPC+failed%3B+curl+92+HTTP%2F2+stream+was+not+closed+cleanly%3A+CANCEL+err+8+bytes+of+body+are+still+expected+fetch-pack%3A+unexpected+disconnect+while+reading+sideband+packet+early
